# Adding divs above scrollable div pushes scroll bars below page height

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble adding any HTML elements above a scrollable div without them pushing that div off the bottom of the page. It's clearly a 100% height issue but unsure how to resolve.

http://codepen.io/establish/pen/lCGwn

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="stream page">
    <div>THIS IS A DIV</div>
    <div>THIS IS ANOTHER DIV</div>
    <div class="stream-content">
      <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut odio libero, posuere in tortor quis, malesuada ullamcorper ante. Morbi sed orci nisi.</h2>

      <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut odio libero, posuere in tortor quis, malesuada ullamcorper ante. Morbi sed orci nisi.</h2>

      <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut odio libero, posuere in tortor quis, malesuada ullamcorper ante. Morbi sed orci nisi.</h2>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="detail page">
  </div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
  background-color: pink;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.page {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0; 
}

.detail {
  background-color: blue;
  left: 425px;
}

.stream {
  background-color: green;
  width: 425px;
}

.stream-content { 
  overflow-y: scroll;
   height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, But it would look to me as if it's working as intended, The more content above, the more it pushes the content below to a longer scroll? What Browser are you using?

Comment: Chrome and Chrome Canary. It cuts the last part of the H2 off, you can't see the last two words and also you can't see the bottom of the scroll bar or scroll container. They are off the page.

Comment: I think it's the website itself - `codebase`, if you drag downwards, you can view the rest of the content, the site-footer seems to cut into the viewable content as it's a fixed positioned footer. I may be wrong though =) - but is this happening also your Dev site, not only codebase?

Comment: Here's an example: http://oi41.tinypic.com/726lqt.jpg

Comment: Yep, initially happened on dev site so copied across to CodePen to replicate http://imgur.com/Q9eHvW5

Comment: Nope, what you have screenshot there is exposing the pink background container which has overflow: hidden on it. Shouldn't ever show.

Comment: Also, if you remove the 2 extra divs then you can see it acting normally with full scroll height etc

Comment: And if you were to set the height to just `height: 88%`; on the `.stream-content` I'm supposing those two `<div>`s are stubbornly taking that rest of the height up :)

Comment: But in short I guess, I've fiddled around with it for a while now, gawwr :D! Although `position: absolute` does always changes things..